# Not able to connect to Amazon S3 via Tomcat server

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk

I have written a code to list files in amazon s3 bucket , but it gives me this exception :

```
com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to 11.36.134.067:8080 [/11.36.134.067] failed: Connection refused: connect
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleRetryableException(AmazonHttpClient.java:1114)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1064)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:743)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:717)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
    com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4330)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4277)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:4271)
    com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.listObjects(AmazonS3Client.java:835)
    com.focus.re.calibr.service.FileUploadService.list(FileUploadService.java:114)
    com.focus.re.calibr.controller.FileUploadController.list(FileUploadController.java:33)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Code to list files with main method:

```
public class App {

    String bucketName = "buketname";
    String accesskey = "accesskey";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        new App();

    }


    App() throws Exception {

        BasicAWSCredentials basicAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accesskey,
                "secretekey");

        AWSCredentialsProvider awsCredentialsProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(basicAWSCredentials);

        AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration =
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("11.36.134.067:8080", "");

        ClientConfiguration clientCfg = new ClientConfiguration();
        SSLContextBuilder builder = new SSLContextBuilder();

        builder.loadTrustMaterial(null, new

                TrustStrategy() {
                    public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslConnectionSocketFactory =
                new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(builder.build(), new NoopHostnameVerifier());
        clientCfg.getApacheHttpClientConfig().

                withSslSocketFactory(sslConnectionSocketFactory);

        AmazonS3 amazonS3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withCredentials(awsCredentialsProvider)
                .withClientConfiguration(clientCfg)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration)
                .build();

        listAllFiles(amazonS3);


    } 

public void listAllFiles(AmazonS3 amazonS3) {

        ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName);

        ObjectListing objectListing = amazonS3. listObjects (listObjectsRequest);

        objectListing.getObjectSummaries().forEach(
                s3ObjectSummary -> {
                    System.out.println(s3ObjectSummary.getKey() + "  " + s3ObjectSummary.getSize());

                });
    }

}
```

This code will work fine if i run the code by executing the main method , but if i run the code from tomcat server by calling a Spring restful webservice then the exception will occur.

Currently i am using latest Tomcat server 8.5.28 , is there any way to fix this issue ?

Comment: Please don't use your error as the question title. Make it easier for future readers

Comment: Heading changed..

Comment: I think EndpointConfiguration is for AWS Services End point and I believe IP address "11.36.134.067" is not one of AWS IP addresses. Set  EndpointConfiguration to correct AWS Services endpoint like s3.amazonaws.com and I think it will connect to s3 service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EndpointConfiguration` is for *Amazon's* endpoint, not yours. From the [documentation:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/java-dg-region-selection.html#Choosing%20a%20Specific%20Endpoint)

> Each AWS client can be configured to use a specific endpoint within a
>   region by calling the setEndpoint method.
>
> For example, to configure the Amazon EC2 client to use the EU
>   (Ireland) Region, use the following code.
>
> ```
> AmazonEC2 ec2 = new AmazonEC2(myCredentials);
> ec2.setEndpoint("https://ec2.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
> ```